# Is it normal in netty for bidirectionnal communication on multicast to have to create 2 bootstrap?

Tags: java, udp, netty, multicast

I am not new to netty, even with muticast, but this is the first time I need to receive and send at the same time for a multicast program.

I need to code something that could be compared to mDNS. So every instance of my program need to reply to queries, and as such need to be able to receive query and send a reply (in multicast udp).

But the problem is that I can't send a packet without using connect() on the channel that the bootstrap class gives me, and when I do so, it seems I can't receive anymore.

So is it normal to have to create 2 bootstrap, with the only difference is that for the send one I have to connect the channel, and the receive one I must not to it.

It works, but I would like to know if it the right way to do it.

Thanks.

Note: using Netty v4.1.34.Final on JVM 1.8u181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to send by using `DatagramPacket(...)` and specific the remote address in the constructor.

Comment: I can't find this class in netty :/ the closest I can find is DefaultDatagramChannelConfig. How do I have to use it anyway to be able to use my encoder / handler ?

Comment: Sorry it is `DatagramPacket`.

Comment: So you are telling me that I should use a bootstrap where I don't call the connect method on the channel that the bootstrap.bind.sync.channel will return me. Then use something like new DatagramPacket(payload, addr) to send my packet ? if so the encoder is useless ?

Comment: I have tried the modification you are telling me to use, and indeed it works, but I can't seems to use my encoder via the channel initializer, but I can workaround that.

Comment: Please open another question with the code in question and we will see how we can make it work :)